# Java servlet, session: null session gets created, can't invalidate it

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a form that takes a username and passes it to `LoginServlet.java` which in turn:

1. If there's no session: creates a session for that username and forwards the request to `LoginResultView.jsp` which dispays a "Successful login, %username%" message
2. If there already is a session, prints out "wow..." and invalidates the old session:

**form**:

```
<form method="POST" action="LoginResult.do">
  <div>
     <label id="username-label" for="usr">username:</label><br/><br/>
     <input type="text"
            value="Enter a username"
            class="form-control form-input-field form- username-input-field default"
            id = "form-username-input-field" name="login-username"
     >                        
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

**servlet:**

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
     public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws
                                                                        IOException, ServletException {
        String username = request.getParameter("login-username");

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);  

        if (session==null)  {
                session = request.getSession(true);  
                session.setAttribute("loginUsername", username);
                RequestDispatcher view= request.getRequestDispatcher("view/LoginResultView.jsp");
                view.forward(request, response);
        }
        else  {
                response.getWriter().println(
                        "wow, how are you here, " + 
                        session.getAttribute("loginUsername"));
                response.getWriter().println(
                        session.getMaxInactiveInterval());
                session.invalidate();
        }

    }
}
```

I also have a navbar that, if there's no session, displays two buttons: Log In and Sign Up and if there's a session, it displays a `loginUsername` attribute, associated with that session:

```
<% HttpSession session2 = request.getSession(false);
     if (session.getAttribute("loginUsername") != null) {
%>
          <div class="dropdown navbar-link">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
                     type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
                     data-toggle="dropdown"
                     aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Login.jsp">                              
                   <%out.println(session2.getAttribute("loginUsername"));%>
                 </a>
              </button>

              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                 <a class="dropdown-item"
                                     href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">Profile</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item"
                     href="#">Link2</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item"
                  href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/LogoutResult.do">                                
                      Log out
                  </a>
              </div>
     </div>

        <%
             }
             else  {
         %>
             <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Login.jsp"
                class="btn btn-info" role="button">Log in
             </a>

             <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Login.jsp"
                               class="btn btn-info" role="button">Sign up
             </a>


        <%
             }
        %>
```

The problem is this: even if there's seemingly no session (it's the two Log in and Sign Up buttons up there) when I fill up the form and send it to `LoginServlet` I still get a message `wow, how are you here, null 120` (120 is a `session-timeout`, specified in web.xml file). Then, I can only send the form's data by sending the same POST data again (I click the round Renew button and click OK on save previous data). Only after that do I get the `LogoutResultView.jsp` page.

Why does this happen? Where does this `null` session comes from? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session you get is *not* null. Otherwise you would get an NPE.

You need to put the `session="false"` attribute into the `<%@page%>` directive of your Navbar JSP. Otherwise, a session is immediately generated when the JSP is first visited.
For example:`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" session="false"
         import="java.util.*" %>`
```

The `session` attribute defaults to true, so if you don't have it explicitely, a session will always be created in the background if none exists.

So, `if (session.getAttribute("loginUsername") != null)` does not generate a NPE, as it usually would.

If you put `session="false"` into your page directive, the check must be `if ( session == null )`. That's want you want.

Comment: Do I need to put it at the top of every jsp page I have? I tried to, but had to edit the directive due to errors, so it's like this now: `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" session="false"
         import="java.util.*" %>`. The null session still lives ;(

Comment: Yes, I would put session="false" into the page directive on every jsp. So control the session creation by your own code in any case. Also, you should not create a `session2` object. (All the more, since you use the built-in `session` later on.) The built-in `session` variable that is created by the JSP Framework is always there; it gets created by the Framework by the instruction `HttpSession session = request.getSession( valueFromTheSessionAttributeInPageDirective );`